# Android Compose - How to draw a Transparent Rect to make a separation in a Box?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to draw a Transparent Rectangle in order to split my Box.

I have found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590695/how-to-clip-or-cut-a-composable) what I needed to clip/cut my Composable by drawing a Transparent Rect.

Here is my code:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(35.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .drawWithLayer {
            drawContent()
            val rect = Rect(
                offset = Offset(x = size.width / 2f, y = 0f),
                size = Size(width = 10.dp.value, height = size.height),
            )
            rotate(
                degrees = 35F,
                pivot = rect.center
            ) {
                drawRect(
                    blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut,
                    color = Color.Transparent,
                    topLeft = rect.topLeft,
                    size = rect.size,
                )
            }
        }
) {
```

Result :

[image]

This is the intended behaviour, but I don't understand why when I rotate the rectangle, it doesn't take the whole height?

EDIT:

After trying the solution by changing the height of the transparent rectangle, this is what I got.

[image]

It's almost the expected result, but the top part of the rectangle doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trigonometry, you can achieve this.

Code inside `drawWithLayer`

```
drawContent()
val degrees = 35F
val radians = Math.toRadians(degrees.toDouble()).toFloat()

val dividerWidth = 10.dp.value

// Divider height = slant height of the divider + twice the slany height of the divider width
val dividerHeight = (size.height / cos(radians)) + (2 * dividerWidth * sin(radians))

// Both x and y offset would be required
val rect = Rect(
    offset = Offset(
        x = size.width / 2F,
        y = -(dividerHeight - size.height) / 2,
    ),
    size = Size(
        width = dividerWidth,
        height = dividerHeight,
    ),
)
rotate(
    degrees = degrees,
    pivot = rect.center,
) {
    drawRect(
        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut,
        color = Color.Blue,
        topLeft = rect.topLeft,
        size = rect.size,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in reality, the perpendicular height is smaller after rotation. The good thing is you dont need trigonmetry to dynamically extend the height, the `clip` in your parent box will save you from render draws. just extend the smaller rectangles height. x2 is reasonable in you're use case:

```
size = rect.size.copy(y = rect.size.y * 2)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I change height x2 or x4 or x10

Comment: Thanks for the update, true that only the bottom part gets extended. Abhimanyu posted a better answer, seems like trig ratios are necessary. But I'd like to add my 2 cents if it would be less complex by offsetting in `-x` and then increasing the size?