# Compose - Remove part of background of an image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas, jetpack-compose-drawscope

I'd like to create a component with following result, assuming that the leaf is an existing ImageVector

[image]

With the following code:

```
@Composable
fun MyIcon(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Image(imageVector = leafImageVector)
        Ring( // the part that need to be removed from Image
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .padding(
                    end = 4.dp,
                    bottom = 8.dp
                ),
        )
        Badge(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .padding(
                    end = 8.dp,
                    bottom = 8.dp
                ),
            badgeColor = badgeColor
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Ring(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier.size(8.dp),
        onDraw = {

            val strokeWidth = 8f
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black, // Change this to Transparent or Unspecified does not help
                radius = 12f,
                style = Stroke(
                    width = strokeWidth
                )
            )

        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun Badge(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    badgeColor: Color,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(8.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(
                badgeColor
            )
    )
}
```

The black part is the part I need to be removed from the Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BlendMod`s inside `Modifier.drawWithContent` to remove some part of Composable, it doesn't necessarily need to be Image for this to work. You can clip or cut from any Composable.

[How to clip or cut a Composable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590695/how-to-clip-or-cut-a-composable)

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ImageEraseTest() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(32.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(80.dp)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
                }
                .drawWithContent {
                    val radius = 16.dp.toPx()
                    val badgeRadius = 12.dp.toPx()

                    val center = Offset(
                        size.width - radius ,
                        size.height - radius
                    )
                    
                    // Destination
                    drawContent()
                    
                    // Source
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Transparent,
                        radius = radius,
                        center = center,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                    )

                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        radius = badgeRadius,
                        center = center
                    )
                },
            imageVector = Icons.Default.AccountCircle,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

You can also draw red circle if you wish to as in example above.

Comment: You are welcome. BlendMode or Porter-Duff modes are very power tools when you wish to manipulate pixels. You can also check the link in the answer and links attached in that answer for more examples.